# What does "the customer is eager-loaded automatically when it's needed." mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand this part of [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-belongs-to-includes) on RailsGuide.

> There's no need to use includes for immediate associations - that is, if you have Order belongs_to :customer, then the customer is eager-loaded automatically when it's needed.

What does "the customer is eager-loaded automatically when it's needed." mean?

Answer (score 0):

When the instance(s) of order (from Class Order) are retrieved from the db, due to the foreign key relationship to it's customer,  their is a strong likelihood that you will use this relationship, (i.e. order.customer.last_name.)  Because of this, ActiveRecord automatically retrieves (and builds) the customer instance so it will not have to go back to the db again when you use the relationship.

Comment: Thanks! But in your case,`order.customer.last_name` issues another SQL.